# Filter element of list of map and then return map in java 8+

Tags: java

I'd like to filter element of list of map and then return map in java 8+

```
public class Test {
    List<Employee> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(emp1);                   // emp1's  filterEmployee return true    
    list1.add(emp2);                   // emp2's  filterEmployee return true  
    list1.add(emp3);                   // emp3's  filterEmployee return false  

    List<Employee> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(emp4);                    // emp4's  filterEmployee return false        
    list2.add(emp5);                    // emp5's  filterEmployee return true 
    list2.add(emp6);                    // emp6's  filterEmployee return true 

    map.put("Sales", list1);
    map.put("Tech", list2);



    public Map<Department, List<Employee>> getEmployeeByDepartment( Map<Department, List<Employee>> map)
    {
        return map1;
    }   

    static boolean filterEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        check employee something and filter out based on some critiea
        and return true or false based on that
    }
}
```

in getEmployeeByDepartment method, for each entry in the map, 
   filter employee in list of the map value by using filterEmployee method below and returned map1 will contains the map such that

<"Sales", list1.add(emp1)>                  // emp1's  filterEmployee return true

<"Sales", list1.add(emp2)>                 // emp2's  filterEmployee return true

<"Tech", list2.add(emp5)>                   // emp5's  filterEmployee return true

<"Tech", list2.add(emp6)>                   // emp6's  filterEmployee return true

I've been trying this and that like below, but  didn't work

```
Map<Department, List<Employee>> map2 = map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().filter(Test::filterEmployee).collect(Collectors.toMap((Department)entry.getKey(), (List<Employee>)entry.getValue())));
```

Comment: Unfortunately the way you've phrased the question it's a bit difficult to work out what you are asking. I think you're saying you have a `Map<String,List<Employee>>` and you want to produce another map of the same type where the lists of employees have been filtered by some criteria. Is that correct?

Comment: @sprinter yes right.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
Predicate<Employee> test;
Map<Department,List<Employee>> map;
```

You have several options:

An in-place change to the map:

```
map.values().forEach(el -> el.removeIf(Predicate.not(test)));
```

Inserting into a new map:

```
Map<Department,List<Employee>> result = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((d, el) -> result.put(d, el.stream().filter(test).collect(toList()));
```

Create via stream processing:

```
Map<Department,List<Employee>> result = map.keySet().stream()
    .collect(toMap(d -> d, d -> map.get(d).stream().filter(test).collect(toList())));
```

There are other options as well but those are the most obvious ones.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
private static boolean shouldKeep(Employee employee) { ... }

// ...

Map<Department, List<Employee>> employees = // a map you've built

// ...

Map<Department, List<Employee>> filteredMap =
                employees.entrySet().stream().collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                e -> e.getKey(),
                                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                                        .filter(employee -> shouldKeep(employee))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```